# Run python script when a file has been added to a folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts, directory

Is it possible to run a Python script when a file has been added to a folder?

In my scenario I have a folder that contains movies and the Python script gets the details (name, year, plot, rating, etc) from OMDb and puts them into a file, which MySQL uses.

Every time I add a movie I have to run the Python script.

I want to know if it is possible to automatically run the Python script when a file has been added to the folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `OMDb`, or `IMDb`?

Comment: OMDb, http://www.omdbapi.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Considering a unique folder where you add files often.**

- Build a script (Python and Bash are good options) that loops for folder size every 'n' seconds (or minutes, how often do you add files?).
- Whenever a new file is created, the size will change and the script should trigger a function that search the last file added and get necessary file info and launches your Python script.

You could easily integrate the above descriptions to your existing Python script.

**If you have several folders, you could make it recursive.**

Let me know if you can't realize how to do it and I will help you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper script `watch_folder`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1"
if [ "${FILE##*.}" = "mov" ]
then
    your_python_script "$2/$1"
fi
exit 0
```

Make it executable:

```bash
chmod +x watch_folder
```

Watch your folder:

```bash
inoticoming your_movie_folder path_of_watch_folder_script {} your_movie_folder \;
```

Your Python script is started on every new file in the folder with the full path of the file name.

Comment: I might add `sudo apt install inoticoming`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `lenord's` solution, here is the python script.

```
import os
import time

# define path for file
source = "path_to_folder"

while True:
    if [f for f in os.listdir(source) if not f.startswith('.')] != []:
        # Some Work
        time.sleep(5)   # Its just to wait if 'Some Work' is very small
    else:
        print('Empty')
        time.sleep(5)
```